# Erlang - что же это за зверь?

Tags: erlang

Если Лисп — это язык, где всё — список,
а Руби — где всё — объект,
то Erlang — это такой язык, в котором всё — процесс.

Интересно кто-нибудь программирует на нем? Поделитесь пожалуйста. Расскажите о проектах.

Comment: *Inside Erlang – создатель языка Joe Armstrong рассказывает краткую иторию создания Erlang*
[![Inside Erlang – создатель языка Joe Armstrong рассказывает краткую иторию создания Erlang]](https://img.youtube.com/vi/2T3dgKhoU6U/0.jpg)](https://youtu.be/2T3dgKhoU6U)

Answer (score 5):

Да, erlang используется в "боевых" проектах.

На эту тему есть интересная лекция Льва Валкина, найти лекцию можно по ссылке http://www.slideshare.net/j2a/ss-4625844.

Если после ознакомления с лекцией появился интерес к этому языку, то рекомендую сервер [сообщества erlang разработчиков.](http://trapexit.org/) На этом сервере есть достаточно документации и готовых рецептов, также здесь аккумулируются ссылки на блоги разработчиков.

Из литературы - [Joe Armstrong "Programming Erlang: Software for a Concurrent World"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3645143/). На русском языке, к сожалению, достойной литературы нет.

Ну и ссылка на официальный сайт, где можно узнать о предстоящих событиях, скачать дистрибутивы, найти документацию и т.п. [http://erlang.org/.](http://erlang.org/)

Comment: Есть перевод Armstrong'а "Programming Erlang" https://github.com/dyp2000/Russian-Armstrong-Erlang

Comment: Теперь есть и на GitBook: https://www.gitbook.com/book/dyp2000/russian-armstrong-erlang/details

Comment: Яркое представление и обучение Erlang: https://learnyousomeerlang.com/